# Custom Cordova Plugin, release a kept callback without calling it

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm creating a plugin for iOS and Android.

For some of my plugin methods, I return a Cordova result which I set it's `keepCallback` property to `true`, so I can execute this callback later as well.

However, at a certain point I'd like to remove this callback *without* having to execute it.
(Usually to dispose of a kept callback, you would execute it with a cordova result where it's `keepCallback` property is set to `false`).

So my question is, how to dispose of a kept callback without having to execute it again (using keepCallback=false)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that sending a plugin result with type `CDVCommandStatus_NO_RESULT` can be used to execute no callback, seems to fit my requirement, so I guess that's it.